# Autolayouts warning,Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, autolayout, constraints

Tableview is displaying in iphone5 ,but in other than iphone 5  i am getting this warning.could some one lemme know what is this warning all about?

```
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008a820 UIImageView:0x7f8193515be0.height == 0.75*UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f81935153f0.height - 21   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008d2a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f81935153f0.height == 0.5   (active)>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x60800008d2a0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f81935153f0.height == 0.5   (active)>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints, will attempt to recover by breaking constraint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11664115/unable-to-simultaneously-satisfy-constraints-will-attempt-to-recover-by-breakin)

Comment: Kindly refer the following related links
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36863042/8472539
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14327470/8472539

Answer (score 0):

You have a constraint conflict, you could solve this by adding different priorities to your constraints, or deleting one of them.
You could also, give all the views you're using a restoration id, so in place of "UIImageView:0x7f8193515be0.height", it would appear 'id name'.height. This way you could see which view is having trouble with constraints.
You should study autolayout if you don't want to have these problems again...
[AutoLayout guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, try to change priorities for each height constraint in your table view cell to be at least 999.f
Obviously, you have an issue with height constraint.